# Change value of name attribute on root xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://url..." name="nameOfApp">

<test> asd </test>

</application>
```

I would like to rename the root `name` attribute, so its like this:

```
<application xmlns="http://url..." name="newName">
```

Notice how its now `newName`

Here is my `xsl`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:t="http://url...">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="application/@name">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="newName"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

First part is just identity transform, but then I try to change the `name` attribute value, but it does not work.

I tried other sourced on SE, but they all referred to the name attribute as the "name of the tag", I have something different. What am I doing wrong? The result after remains unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are VERY close. You have just two small problems in your matcher.

- You forgot the **namespace** `t:` for the element `application`
- Since you want to insert **static text** as value, you have to **quote** it as `'newName'`

Here is a fixed version

```
<xsl:template match="t:application/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="'newName'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```